# Java entity not mapping to ElasticSearch GeoPoint property

Tags: java, elasticsearch, geo, spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm develop a microservice for manage locations with Java/Spring Boot using spring-data-elasticsearch and when try to enter new data to ES using my controller the data input is not mapped properly to a document into ES, specifically the Geopoint attribute "location".

I'm tried using GeoPoint from import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.geo.GeoPoint and from org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.geo.GeoPoint, in both cases data saved to ES is not typed as geo_point

```java
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Document;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Field;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.FieldType;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.GeoPointField;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.geo.GeoPoint;

import io.swagger.annotations.ApiModelProperty;

@Document(indexName = "location", type="location")
public class Location {

    @Id
    @ApiModelProperty(hidden = true)
    private String id;

    private String appId;

    private String resourceId;

    @GeoPointField
    private GeoPoint location;

    private String street;

    private String city;

    // more attr and method was ommited

}
```

After save data into ES using ElasticSearchRepository when I get mapping data is showed like:

```
{
  "location" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "location" : {
        "properties" : {
          "appId" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          },
          "city" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          },
          "country" : {
            "properties" : {
              "countryCcFips" : {
                "type" : "text",
                "fields" : {
                  "keyword" : {
                    "type" : "keyword",
                    "ignore_above" : 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "countryCcIso" : {
                "type" : "text",
                "fields" : {
                  "keyword" : {
                    "type" : "keyword",
                    "ignore_above" : 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "countryName" : {
                "type" : "text",
                "fields" : {
                  "keyword" : {
                    "type" : "keyword",
                    "ignore_above" : 256
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "location" : {
            "properties" : {
              "lat" : {
                "type" : "float"
              },
              "lon" : {
                "type" : "float"
              }
            }
          },
          "parish" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
// ommited more json data
```

Please, I need that GeoPoint field (location) will mapped to geo_point into ES, is important to execute Geoqueries properly.

I'm , using Spring Data ElasticSearch, with Spring Boot 2.1.3.RELEASE and ElasticSearch driver 6.4.3 with ElasticSearch server 6.4

Comment: That's strange indeed, I just checked the code, normally you would just need to have either the `GeoPoint` class or the `GeoPointField` annotation to have the field typed as "geo_point". This place in the code hasn't changed for years. I will try to reproduce this with a local example, but can't promise that I will find the time today.

Answer (score 3):

I have created a minimal application with a repository, a controller and am running this with Spring Boot 2.1.3.RELEASE, Spring Data Elasticsearch 3.1.5.RELEASE, elasticsearch client 6.4.3 and an Elasticsearch server 6.4.0.

I am using a `Person` pojo class that has two geo_point fields, one is a normal spring `GeoPoint` and one a custom `MyGeoPoint` that uses the `GeoPointField`annotation.

After starting the application and inserting a record by calling the RestController's `init` method, the mapping in the index are alright:

```
{
  "person": {
    "aliases": {},
    "mappings": {
      "person": {
        "properties": {
          "firstName": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "geoPoint": {
            "type": "geo_point"
          },
          "id": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "lastName": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "myGeoPoint": {
            "type": "geo_point"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "settings": {
      "index": {
        "refresh_interval": "1s",
        "number_of_shards": "5",
        "provided_name": "person",
        "creation_date": "1554750620775",
        "store": {
          "type": "fs"
        },
        "number_of_replicas": "1",
        "uuid": "w1L279wOQUmvDPMu4iYXtg",
        "version": {
          "created": "6040099"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Person.java**

```
/*
 * (c) Copyright 2019 sothawo
 */
package com.sothawo.springdataelastictest;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Document;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.GeoPointField;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.geo.GeoPoint;

/**
 * @author P.J. Meisch (pj.meisch@sothawo.com)
 */
@Document(indexName = "person", type = "person")
public class Person {
    @Id private Long id;
    private String lastName;
    private String firstName;

    private GeoPoint geoPoint;

    @GeoPointField private MyGeoPoint myGeoPoint;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public GeoPoint getGeoPoint() {
        return geoPoint;
    }

    public void setGeoPoint(GeoPoint geoPoint) {
        this.geoPoint = geoPoint;
    }

    public MyGeoPoint getMyGeoPoint() {
        return myGeoPoint;
    }

    public void setMyGeoPoint(MyGeoPoint myGeoPoint) {
        this.myGeoPoint = myGeoPoint;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", lastName='" + lastName + '\'' +
                ", firstName='" + firstName + '\'' +
                ", geoPoint=" + geoPoint +
                ", myGeoPoint=" + myGeoPoint +
                '}';
    }

    public static class MyGeoPoint {
        private double lat;
        private double lon;

        public double getLat() {
            return lat;
        }

        public void setLat(double lat) {
            this.lat = lat;
        }

        public double getLon() {
            return lon;
        }

        public void setLon(double lon) {
            this.lon = lon;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "MyGeoPoint{" + "lat=" + lat + ", lon=" + lon + '}';
        }
    }
}
```

**PersonRepository.java**:

```
package com.sothawo.springdataelastictest;

import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.ElasticsearchRepository;

public interface PersonRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<Person, Long> {}
```

**ElasticsearchRepositoryController.java**:

```
package com.sothawo.springdataelastictest;

import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.geo.GeoPoint;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/repo")
public class ElasticsearchRepositoryController {

    private PersonRepository personRepository;

    public ElasticsearchRepositoryController(PersonRepository personRepository) {
        this.personRepository = personRepository;
    }

    @GetMapping("/init")
    public Long initPerson() {
        final Person person = new Person();
        person.setId(42L);
        person.setFirstName("John");
        person.setLastName("Doe");

        GeoPoint geoPoint = new GeoPoint(12.34, 56.78);
        person.setGeoPoint(geoPoint);

        Person.MyGeoPoint myGeoPoint = new Person.MyGeoPoint();
        myGeoPoint.setLat(43.21);
        myGeoPoint.setLon(87.65);
        person.setMyGeoPoint(myGeoPoint);

        return personRepository.save(person).getId();

    }
}
```

**SpringdataElasticTestApplication.java**:

```
package com.sothawo.springdataelastictest;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.config.EnableElasticsearchRepositories;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories
public class SpringdataElasticTestApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringdataElasticTestApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

So I cannot find a problem with this code and the versions I used. Can you reproduce the error with these classes or build a minimal example that reproduces the error?

Are you sure, that the mapping is created by the Repository class and not somewhere else?

And can you please check the mapping *after* the application is started, but *before* any data is inserted into the index?

Comment: How did you create your index? For me it creates in a way which does not have geo_point!!

Comment: The index is created automatically on startup if it does not exist

Comment: I found out that for Geo Point, dynamic mapping does not work and has to be done manually or enforced through code. Also, I tried your provided solution with specified versions and it did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, after I deleted an Index **during the runtime of the application** (`spring-boot` `2.2.1.RELEASE` with `spring-data-elasticserach` `4.0.0.DATAES-690-SNAPSHOT`).

After I saved a document, the index hat the **wrong mapping** for the location property:

```
... other properites...

"location" : {
  "properties" : {
    "lat" : {
      "type" : "float"
    },
    "lon" : {
      "type" : "float"
    }
  }
}
```

I could not solve it during the runtime of the application, the mapping was always wrong.

**This solution worked for me:**

1. delete the index
2. restart the application

Now the index was created with *JUST* the location field, all other field-mappings missing. After indexing documents (with `ElasticSearchRepository.save`), everything was fine, the other mappings where added.

```
{
    "properties": {
        "location": {
            "type": "geo_point"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem but I solved it this way:
On the ES side, create the index like this:

```
PUT my_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "doc.location": {
        "type": "geo_point"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In `location` is the field that I want to be geo_point type. Excuse my English.
Of course, ES must follow the following structure for its persistence:

```
"location": { 
    "lat": 41.12,
    "lon": -71.34
}
```

You said it [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.4/geo-point.html).

Comment: Explain your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem but after some documentation surfing I had to use the following code snippet to get the Elasticsearch to create my `GeoPoint` property as a `geo_point` typed field.

```
@Autowired
private ElasticsearchRestTemplate elasticsearchRestTemplate;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    IndexOperations indexOperations = elasticsearchRestTemplate.indexOps(PropertySearch.class);
    indexOperations.putMapping(indexOperations.createMapping());
    indexOperations.refresh();
}
```

For more information you can refer [post](http://shazsterblog.blogspot.com/2020/11/spring-data-elasticsearch-geopoint.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (elasticsearchRestTemplate.indexOps(MerchantModel.class).exists()) {
    elasticsearchRestTemplate.indexOps(MerchantModel.class).delete();
}
// fix geo_point mapping
CreateIndexRequest createIndexRequest = new CreateIndexRequest("merchant");
createIndexRequest.mapping("{\n" +
        "      \"properties\": {\n" +
        "        \"location\": {\n" +
        "          \"type\": \"geo_point\"\n" +
        "        }\n" +
        "      }\n" +
        "    }", XContentType.JSON);
IndicesClient indicesClient = restHighLevelClient.indices();
CreateIndexResponse createIndexResponse = indicesClient.create(createIndexRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
log.info("create ES merchant mapping:[isAcknowledged={}]", createIndexResponse.isAcknowledged());
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.